# JSON parsing VBA Won't work on Excel 365 but working on Previous Excel versions

Tags: json, excel, parsing

I have been wrestling with this issue since a long time. And I have received no legit answer to my query yet. This code Extracts the test steps from the json file. https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

```
Dim j As Object
Set j = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JSON)
Set Var = j("issues") ' second level array
For Each issue In Var
Set Var2 = issue("fields")("customfield_10104")("steps")
For Each Step In Var2 ' third level objects
Cells(Col, 1).Value = issue("key")
Cells(Col, 2).Value = issue("fields")("description")
Cells(Col, 3).Value = Step("index")
Cells(Col, 4).Value = Step("fields")("Action")
Cells(Col, 5).Value = Step("fields")("Data")
Cells(Col, 6).Value = Step("fields")("Expected Result")
Col = Col + 1
Next Step
Next issue
```

The data comes from a JIRA API. Te problem i am dealing with is it's working fine for me in Excel 2010 but breaks in Excel 365. Returns an error on 'Set Var2...'.

Any help or suggestions for improvement are really appreciated.

Comment: You may want to consider an alternative to import json to Excel instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/json

Comment: Without a JSON (posted as text) that demonstrates the problem, it will be difficult to help you.